# How to find whether a given object is receiving shadow in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js, shader

In a huge scene (~10k objects), I have a moving light. All objects can cast a shadow and receive shadow. At any given time (i.e. location of the light), the objective is to know which all objects are shaded (and not just which all capable of receiving shading). Is there a way for the same?

Light being used is directional light and MeshLambertMaterial is material for the objects. One way to know is to create rays from light to each material and see if the light is intersecting any other object, but my assumption is since shadows are being created it will be redundant to do ray tracing. Also, one needs to create multiple rays originating from each point of the object to the light and thus, have to reduce the answer to discrete simplification.